# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 194-195: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

Hi there i am trying to run a quite commplicated cmd command in python but i keep on getting the error in the title! Here's the command:

```
os.system('cmd /c dotnet DicordChatExporter.CLI\DiscordChatExporter.CLi.dll export -t "[insert discord token here]" -c 939905115505180682 -o C:\Users\Danny\DiscordExports\log.txt -f PlainText')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` has special meaning in `python` strings, so you need escape it by doubling to get literal `\`, all `\` in all paths should be replaced using `\\`, for example

```
C:\Users\Danny\DiscordExports\log.txt
```

should be

```
C:\\Users\\Danny\\DiscordExports\\log.txt
```